# GO: Object in another file (same package) throws undefined error

Tags: go

File: $GOPATH/src/scratch_go_code/main/main.go

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello World")
    cloud := Cloud{}
    cloud.Say()
}
```

file $GOPATH/src/scratch_go_code/main/cloud.go

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Cloud struct{}

func (Cloud) Say() {
    fmt.Println("I'm a cloud in the main package")
}
```

Running: go install scratch_go_code/... && go run main/main.go
throws:

```
# command-line-arguments
main/main.go:7: undefined: Cloud
```

Any idea why?

Comment: For future reference: don't call your packages "main" (i.e. `package main` is fine, but don't name the containing folder `main/`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
go build scratch_go_code/main
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to either use `go build` or pass both files to `go run`, example :

```
go run main/*.go
```

using go build :

```
cd scratch_go_code/ && go build && ./scratch_go_code
```

Comment: could you give me an example on go build? I tried go build scratch_go_code/... && go run main/main.go - that didn't work ...